# How to resize SKScene in editor?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, xcode6, skscene

I've designed an SKScene for iPhone 4S in landscape (960x640)

I now want to use the same scene on iPhone 5, 6 etc

Is there any way to "easily" adapt this scene? I mean in a way similar to AutoLayout for Storyboards.

I don't want to have to copy this scene for each size and move everything again manually.

The Scale Mode is Aspect Fit, but that doesn't use the whole screen. Aspect Fill causes some sprites to be partially off-screen.

Comment: I tried setting SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill. That did not work. I have also tried resetting the scene file, like this:

    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    [self setSize:screenSize];
. Doesn't work. 
I'm quite disappointed in limited the sprite kit scene editor is in xcode. I was hoping to use it for level design, but it is just far too basic to do anything useful with it.